# Two div block z-index

Tags: html, css

There are two div blocks. The first one has `z-index: 0`, another one has `z-index: -1`. How to show the text on top of everything in the block whose `z-index: -1`. I put in the text style `cursor: pointer`.

```
.first-block image as pizza {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 700;
}

#second block when circle has some text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  right: -20%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#text div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov yes

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov

 .first-block image as pizza{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 700;
}     
 #second block when circle has some text {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15%;
    right: -20%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#text div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add all relevant HTML and CSS there?

Comment: @AbzalKenzhegulov please edit your post and add your relevant HTML and CSS in your post, so that we will be able to test it directly

Comment: please make a working snippet

Comment: @AbzalKenzhegulov What about HTML?

Comment: Your CSS seems invalid: `.first-block image as pizza { ... }`. Given how CSS works, this rule will apply to a `<pizza>`-element inside an `<as>`-element inside an `<image>`-element, inside something with class '.first-block'. But none of those 3 elements exist in HTML.

Comment: @PeterB I know =) It is just description

Comment: CSS will treat it as elements. If you want comments in CSS, use `/* ... */` e.g. `.first-block /* image as pizza */ { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your request, you should trying to do something similar.
If you post your html and css code in the question, we could help you better! :)

```
/*image as pizza*/
.first-block { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 700;
}

/*block when circle has some text*/
#second { 
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  right: -20%;
  /*z-index: -1;I suggest you to remove this one, as it would be under the pizza anyway, because pizza have z-index 700.*/
}

/*div*/
#text { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 701; /*And add here(The DIV in which your text is nested) the z-index*/
}
```

EDIT:

```
<div class="first-block">img of pizza under the text but over the circle.<div>
<div id="second"> <!--This is the circle divin which the text is nested.-->
  <div id="text">
   SOME TEXT OVER THE PIZZA'S IMAGE.
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: It  works!! But I need  it is two block have to be in one div block =).

Comment: I've edit the answer for show the structure better :)